# Show that for all integers : If  is an integer such that |+7 and |2+9, then |58.

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

This is the working out I have so far. Any checks to see if it is sufficient would be highly appreciated!

Since $|+7$,

$| (n+7)^2= n^2+14n+49.$

By adding $(n^2+9)$, we get:

$n^2+14n+49 +(n^2+9)$

$=2n^2+14n+58$

$=2n(n+7)+58.$

Therefore,
$| (n+7)^2 + (n^2+9) -2n(n+7)=58.$

My tutor has told me to add more insightful explanations and fix my last line however i don't really know what that means. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This looks good.  $\quad$.

Comment: Looks all correct to me too, but it meanders a little bit. What you've really done is to add/subtract multiples of $n+7$ to $n^2+9$ so as to get rid of any $n^2$ and $n$ terms, leaving only the integer $58$. With that in mind, it is a little odd that you first *add* $n^2+14n+49$ to $n^2+9$ for some reason, rather than subtract it to get rid of the $n^2$ as the first step. This is essentially [polynomial division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division).

Comment: What does $n2$ mean? Do you mean $n^2$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If $d\mid n^2+9$ and $d\mid n+7$, then $d\mid n^2+9-(n+7)(n-7)=58$